# Android/Java: how to send notifications to user, even when app is not "actively" being used?

Tags: java, android, parse-server

I want to be able to send a notification to a user IF something changes.
For example,  my application is crime-related. So users can submit reports of crimes that have happened in their neighborhoods.

When a new crime is reported, I want to be able to send ALL users in that specific neighbourhood a notification, even if they are not actively using the app.

How can this be done? I'm quite new at this but to my understanding services like Firebase Messaging require you to type out a message manually and select users to send the message to manually. I'm wondering if there's a way this can be done without someone having to manually do work?

Similar to how snapchat/instagram and stuff will send you notifications that someone has sent you a message even when you are not using your phone.

In my case, I just want the same standard notification "New crime in your area" to be displayed...

How can I do this? (Currently for notifications I'm just using Notification Channels), thank you so much!

Comment: You completely misunderstand Firebase Cloud Messaging.  They aren't generally text messages at all.  Its just a PUSH messaging implementation, and is totally meant for this usecase

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily do this using Parse Server through FCM integration.

## First, you need to setup your Android app to be able to receive push notifications

Just follow this Quickstart: https://docs.parseplatform.org/parse-server/guide/#push-notifications-quick-start

## Second, you need to create a cloud code function

I suggest you to create a cloud code function that will receive the neighborhood as parameter, will query for the user installations in that neighborhood and send the push notification to all of them.

It would be something like this:

```js
Parse.Cloud.define('notifyCrime', async req => {
  const query = new Parse.Query(Parse.Installation);
  query.equalTo('neighborhood', req.params.neighborhood); // I'm supposing you have a field called neighborhood in your installation class - if not, you can save this field there when the user sign up
  await Parse.Push.send({
    where: query,
    data: {
      alert: 'There is a crime in your neighborhood'
    },
    useMasterKey: true
  });
});
```

Reference: https://docs.parseplatform.org/js/guide/#sending-pushes-to-queries

## Third, you need to call the cloud function from your Android app

Once some user has reported a crime, you can call the cloud code function that you created in step 2 to notify all other users in the same neighborhood.

It would be something like this:

```java
HashMap<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
params.put("neighborhood", "The neighborhood goes here");
ParseCloud.callFunctionInBackground("notifyCrime", params, new FunctionCallback<Object>() {
   void done(Object response, ParseException e) {
       if (e == null) {
          // The users were successfully notified
       }
   }
});
```

Reference: https://docs.parseplatform.org/cloudcode/guide/#cloud-functions

Comment: hi! thank you so much for your detailed answer :) I'm quite new at this so I might be a little confused but, the code in the links you sent me doesn't seem to be in Java? Can I find a Java equivalent?

Comment: The first step has a link teaching you how to setup your android java code for receiving the push notifications. The second link is written in javascript. For security reason you should not send push notifications directly from the client. It would be a security breach and a hacker could send a bad message to all your users. So you need to create a cloud code function in javascript that will send the push in the server side. In the third step the code is in java and shows how you will call the cloud code function from your android java app.

Answer (score 0):

**"my understanding services like Firebase Messaging require you to type out a message manually and select users to send the message to manually".**

This is not completely true. There is a method name Firebase [Topic Messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/topic-messaging), that lets you send notifications to specific user segments only. You have to register from the app for that topic and then, you can send customized message to your user groups based on topics they subscribed to.

Comment: Its not true at all.  FCM is a push messaging solution.  OP seems to think its a chat mechanism (you can build chat on top of it, but its not a chat protocol).

Comment: I don't think it's a chat mechanism, I realize it's for push messages but my understanding of FCM is that I need to sign in and type a message to send. How do I avoid this so that it will do it automatically when a new report is submitted for example?

Comment: @GabeSechan where from the idea of "chat" comes in? if his requirement is to send notifications which are not time critical, what's wrong with using topic messaging?

Comment: @keyoshi998 I don't know where you got that impression, but its totally wrong.  There's even a way to do what you just described.  It doesn't send text messages, and it doesn't show notifications.  Its a way of sending data.  And if your app doesn't explicitly do something with that data, there's no output anywhere.  There may be a webapp somewhere that sends a specific packet to some machine, but its never been used for anything other than testing purposes.

Comment: @GabeSechan thanks for the clarification. your comment was misleading for me, as it doesn't mention the context. I thought it was talking anything else. Thanks anyways :)